# How to print a string array that has a byte value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a array declared as

```
char **a;
```

I am reading from a byte file, and saving the information in the array
Here is the part where I have a question about

```
//Allocate memory is not shown here

  fp = fopen(file, "rb");  
  for (i = 0; i < LN; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < SN; j++)
      bytesread = fread(&a[(int)i][(int)j], sizeof(char), 1, fp);
       printf("%d \n", &a[(int)i][(int)j]);
  }
```

When I print the value of the array each time, it does not give me the correct answer.
When i change %d to %s is gives me an empty value.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Just a quibble: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, because `sizeof` returns sizes as number of `char`s. The language standard says so. Don't write it out. Also, do not use casts unless you have to **and** know they are correct.

Comment: And if you feel the need to cast `i` and `j` for index calculations, you must have something fundamentally wrong in your declarations.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't have too much of a problem with sizeof(char). Imo it's more descriptive, especially to those who don't remember the docs for fread. The casts are scary though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the address of the item. Change your printf to

```
printf("%d \n", a[(int)i][(int)j]);
```